# How do I decrease the amount of fsync that mysql does?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to import a database into a slave server. The process is being slowed because mysql calls fsync at a crazy rate. The jbd2/dm-0-8 runs at 80 - 99 % continuously but the throughput is quite low. It was running at a few kb/s till I implemented the following changes

```
innodb_flush_sync = OFF
sync_binlog= 0
sync_frm = ON
sync_master_info = 0
sync_relay_log = 10000
sync_relay_log_info = 0
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 0
```

It's now running at about 12Mb/s. I'm sure if I can do something further to decrease fsync calls it will help this.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `innodb_doublewrite = 0` and `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 0` depending on your MySQL version, too, but I wonder if the folks at [dba.se] might have more knowledge than us...

Comment: Thanks. I'll give that a try, on both fronts. I didn't see the Database Administrators forum.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's for dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: Configuring software that runs on Unix is on-topic here. They *may* get better answers at DBA (or may not), but I'm voting to leave open here.